# It looks app is successfully deployed but "heroku open" keeps showing Application error

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I created sinatra app and trying to deploy it on Heroku. When I push heroku with `git push heroku master`, it looks the app is successfully deployed but then when I implement `heroku open` it shows application error.

I created app using sinatra with postgresql DB.

I tried many stuffs but really can't figure out what actually causes the error.

I tried

・Destroyed and recreated heroku app.

・Uninstalled bundler and installed 1.15.2 since 1.17.2 which was installed at first did not work.

・Deleted Gem file and recreated.

・Tried puma.(also modified Procfile with `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`)

etc..

$ git push heroku master

```
Enumerating objects: 573, done.
Counting objects: 100% (573/573), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (559/559), done.
Writing objects: 100% (573/573), 15.77 MiB | 219.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 573 (delta 314), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching backports 3.15.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.17.2
remote:        Fetching mustermann 1.0.3
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Installing mustermann 1.0.3
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Installing backports 3.15.0
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching pg 1.1.4
remote:        Installing pg 1.1.4 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rack 2.0.7
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.7
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Fetching rack-protection 2.0.7
remote:        Installing rack-protection 2.0.7
remote:        Fetching sinatra 2.0.7
remote:        Installing sinatra 2.0.7
remote:        Fetching sinatra-contrib 2.0.7
remote:        Installing sinatra-contrib 2.0.7
remote:        Fetching puma 4.1.1
remote:        Installing puma 4.1.1 with native extensions
remote:        Bundle complete! 5 Gemfile dependencies, 12 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Removing bundler (1.15.2)
remote:        Bundle completed (20.07s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 30.1M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v6
remote:        https://ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/ancient-crag-43793.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

$ heroku logs

```
2019-09-12T03:13:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-09-12T03:13:53.745451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 36930`
2019-09-12T03:13:56.583038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-12T03:13:56.587379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-09-12T03:13:56.555987+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-09-12T03:13:56.503859+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
2019-09-12T03:13:56.503879+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2019-09-12T03:13:56.503881+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2019-09-12T03:13:56.503883+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
2019-09-12T03:13:56.503885+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
2019-09-12T03:13:56.503887+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.rb:11:in `<main>'
2019-09-12T03:13:58.532988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 33962`
2019-09-12T03:14:01.220318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-12T03:14:01.136864+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
2019-09-12T03:14:01.136884+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2019-09-12T03:14:01.136886+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2019-09-12T03:14:01.136888+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
2019-09-12T03:14:01.136890+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
2019-09-12T03:14:01.136892+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.rb:11:in `<main>'
2019-09-12T03:14:01.197593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-09-12T03:16:16.795355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=8859880d-47b9-49f9-b847-2a02099bc855 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:16:17.126133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=5d0bd878-aed7-4625-acc4-86f40c801a46 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:16:17.639402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=91cb566e-dc2c-4806-9790-3b3ba4b72ec3 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:20:09.313587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=9a8430b7-14c9-4794-9de1-69f319b7ec67 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:20:10.696885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=0a479063-1e8e-40bb-82c9-4d149150fe11 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:20:11.220968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=a74ee463-52af-458b-aab9-11181287089a fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:38:07.360350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-09-12T03:38:09.195028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 21707`
2019-09-12T03:38:12.014593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-12T03:38:11.945704+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
2019-09-12T03:38:11.945730+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2019-09-12T03:38:11.945732+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2019-09-12T03:38:11.945778+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
2019-09-12T03:38:11.945780+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
2019-09-12T03:38:11.945786+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.rb:11:in `<main>'
2019-09-12T03:38:11.997334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-09-12T03:42:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user  "my email address"
2019-09-12T03:42:28.853379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-09-12T03:42:28.539461+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 00584404 by user  "my email address"
2019-09-12T03:42:28.539461+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user  "my email address"
2019-09-12T03:42:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-09-12T03:42:30.598759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 12078`
2019-09-12T03:42:33.295521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-12T03:42:33.282712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-09-12T03:42:33.217024+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
2019-09-12T03:42:33.217056+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2019-09-12T03:42:33.217059+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2019-09-12T03:42:33.217077+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
2019-09-12T03:42:33.217080+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
2019-09-12T03:42:33.217087+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.rb:11:in `<main>'
2019-09-12T03:43:03.364089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=f70df879-4c32-4d96-a669-266609b48f93 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-12T03:43:04.119899+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-crag-43793.herokuapp.com request_id=fb27aee3-f2e8-4af8-98c1-ce9479052001 fwd="106.181.207.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

> > could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)

Is DB somehow causing the error..?

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'sinatra/cookies' 
require 'pg'

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

enable :sessions

client = PG::connect(
  :host => "localhost",
  :user => 'tomoyo', :password => '',
  :dbname => "myapp")
```

Comment: one of thing which I can see here is that you passing `my email address` as user, so that is first place which I would look to change.

Comment: Yes, connection refused indicates that your database configuration is wrong. Would be helpful to see how it's configured.

Comment: First, sorry that I forgot to mention that I replaced my actual email address on the logs with text "my email address" to avoid to expose it on public.

I updated how I wrote on top of app.rb which also shows how I configures database. 

Do I need to do any other setting for database? I thought there is no need to be set anything since I use postgresql which is officially supported by Heroic then migration or any action is not required.